# Windows port of /usr/bin/time?

Tags: linux, windows, time, measurement, timing

Is there a clean Windows port / version of the `/usr/bin/time` command in Linux (program to time the execution of a process)?

Comment: What feature of `/usr/bin/time` are you looking for on Windows, specifically?

Comment: The ability to time my programs of course.

Comment: Your question assumes that people know what `time` actually does on Linux. Someone may not use Linux, but may know a Windows Alternative to what you're looking for (which is the ultimate goal of your question) - it would be helpful for those people to state what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: I agree with EvilChookie. +1 now that I understand what you want.

Comment: Please see my answer for a link to `timethis.exe` which does what you want and is available as an approx 116K download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`timethis`](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=913795CD-7026-4143-AE85-1F5E096F9BE0&displaylang=en) from the Win2K resource kit.

Comment: i don't like how it has to clear your terminal when you use it.

Comment: @unknown I have never observed `timethis` clearing the terminal.

Comment: link dead......

Answer (score 3):

I have created a simple Windows program called timemem.exe that behaves similarly to /usr/bin/time on Linux/Mac OS X, and will show similar statistics, such as elapsed time, user and kernel CPU time, and maximum working set size in memory used by another Win32 process.  See:

http://homepage.mac.com/jafingerhut/files/code/code.html

Comment: link dead......

Answer (score 2):

If you want `time` to use it as a benchmark utility, the [Windows 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en) has `Timeit.exe` which does the same.

Comment: Cool, can I get it without getting everything else there?

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to be the only download Microsoft provides. But there are a lot of useful tools in there which I have renamed to their UNIX equivalent and dropped into my System32 folder for use from the command line. You can simply delete the ones which you don't want.

Comment: John T, congrats on being first to 10k! Enjoy reading your posts... Don't know how you find the time as every time I am about to submit, you seem to have the same / slightly better answer! Here's to the next 10k!- Delete this after you have read it as there is no private message feature! (or write another commend then il delete it)

Comment: @Wil, thanks! I cannot delete it and there is no need to. Comments are exactly that, comments. Good ones are rather appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You could always install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) which will give you the UNIX time command. It is pretty useful to have Cygwin installed anyway.

By you asking for a clean port or version, I don't think Cygwin would be acceptable. The only thing I have found is [this](http://www.sambal.org/2008-07/reporting-your-own-cpu-time-on-windows/) for custom code to compile on Windows. As I didn't find any links where this has been set up as the time command, I don't know that you could get this to work unless you wanted to program it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac, `/usr/bin/time` returns the system uptime.

On a Windows computer, you can use the following to return the uptime: `net stats server`

The 'Statistics Since' will give you the time the computer was last powered up. There's also a server tool - uptime.exe

There's more information [at the Microsoft Support Site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555737).

Of course, if you're not looking to find the uptime of a computer, I'm way off the mark. If you're not looking for uptime, what *are* you looking to achieve?

Edit: If you're looking for CPU time as suggested in a comment, you can use the `tasklist` command. Punch in `tasklist /?` at a command prompt and see the info about it.

Comment: I don't think he's looking for uptime. 
time on linux measures the real and cpu time for a process.

Comment: @prestomation: Ah. Edited, adding something else that would help.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but I was searching for a Windows version of /usr/bin/time. Could not find anything, so I wrote a clone:

https://github.com/cbielow/wintime

It can measure

- execution time of a program
- RAM usage (maximum)
- page faults etc...

including logging to a CSV file.
Precompiled binaries are available. Just download and run it.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell already has the built-in capability to measure runtime with the cmdlet [`Measure-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command?view=powershell-7.3)

```
Measure-Command { Get-EventLog "windows powershell" }
```

Of course it can also be called from cmd or any applications

```
powershell -C "Measure-Command { sleep 2 }"
```